# Motorola Bluetooth Low energy readGattCharacterisitics does not return

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on developing an android application on Motorola Razr phone (running android version 2.3.5) for testing Bluetooth low energy device (similar to keyfob of TI's CC2540). I'm using the MOT_BTLE_Stubs.jar provided by Motorola for my application. 
From my application, I'm able to connect to the device. But readGattCharacteristicValue does not seem to be working, which was working sometime back. I'm trying to read the value from a handle. It used to return the value everytime I read in the broadcast receiver. But now it does not respond. I've added an intent filter to receive the ACTION_GATT_CHARACTERISTICS_READ. It does not return the value in broadcast receiver.

I reverted back the old code. It does not work anymore. Looks like there is some configuration problem in the blue tooth settings on the phone. I'm unable to flush the cache contents.
If anyone has faced the same issue and have resolved it please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `ICS_R2`, so no help there. But to flush the cache, root the phone, and delete `/data/misc/bluetoothd`, then reboot the phone:

```
adb shell
su
busybox rm -rf /data/misc/bluetoothd
adb reboot
```